# Can I give fish/bugs I catch in animal crossing new leaf to other people online?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

My girlfriend recently got the game, and I wanna help her out a bit. Is there anyway I can give her fish or bugs?

Comment: You can give her the money from said fish or bugs

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/3ds/997811-animal-crossing-new-leaf/answers/353555-can-i-give-fish-and-bugs-to-friends

You **cannot** give somebody else fish or bugs.